# Ajustar elementos al 100% en móviles desde css

Tags: html, css

Tengo un problema estoy haciendo un sitio prueba en el cual se muestra una estructura con un logo en la parte superior y elementos de menú en la parte baja, etc, etc.

Tienen en css estos elementos la propiedad de `width:100%;` y a primera vista parece que lo imprime bien en el móvil pero si deslizas con el dedo hacia la izquierda resulta que hay espacios en blanco y el sitio pareciera que oculta esos elementos.

Alguna solución por favor :/

Así se imprime antes de deslizarse

[image: Como debería ser]

Y así se ve si deslizan hacia la izquierda

[image: Malo]

[image: Ajustado]

El codigo es el siguiente;

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es" >
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Bla bla bla">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>Pruebas</title>

        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="media/images/logo_ic.ico"><![endif]-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/images/logo_ic.png" />
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="media/images/logo_ic.png">

    </head>

<body>

<!------Header------>

<div class="mheader" >
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="logo" >
            <img class="logo_img" src="media/images/logo.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="menu" >
            <span class="menu_e" ><a href="#" >Link 1</a></span>
            <span class="menu_e" ><a href="#" >Link 2</a></span>
            <span class="menu_e" ><a href="#" >Link 3</a></span>
            <span class="menu_e" ><a href="#" >Link 4</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cut" ></div>

<!------Contenido------>
<br /><br />
<div class="wrapper-big" >

    <div class="wrapper-main" >Bla bla</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#EDEDED;
}

/*------Header------*/

.mheader {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    display:table;
}

.row {
    display:table-row;
}

.row div {
    display:table-cell;
}

.row .logo {
    width:25%;
    padding:5px 0px 0px 5px;
}

.logo_img {
    width:100%;
}

.row .menu {
    width:75%;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:right;
    padding-right:40px;
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#2DAFCF;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:7px;
}

.menu a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#2593A5;
    background-color:#D6EBED;
    padding:7px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .mheader {
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        display:table;
    }

    .row {
    }

    .row div {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .row .logo {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
        padding-top:5px;
        background-color:#2323CC;
    }

    .logo_img {
        width:25%;
    }

    .row .menu {
        width:100%;
        font-size:14px;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:#FFCC35;
        display:table;
    }

    .row .menu a {
        width:100%;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#2DAFCF;
        font-weight:bold;
    }

    .row .menu a:hover {
        width:100%;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#2593A5;
        background-color:#D6EBED;
    }

    .menu_e {
        display: block;
        width:100%;
    }
}

.cut {
    clear:both;
}

/*------Wrapper------*/

.wrapper-big {
    width:100%; 
}

.wrapper-main {
    width:95%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que al mostrarse se ajuste y se muestren los elementos como en la primera imagen y que no existan espacios a un lado que hacen que se vea mal el sitio. GRACIAS Y BUEN DÍA

Comment: Tienes establecido el viewport en el head? De ser así, por favor añade lo que tengas, ¿y estás seguro de que ese es todo el código CSS que tienes? Porque lo he probado y a mi no me ocurre el problema que mencionas.

Comment: Listo, gracias por comentar... he agregado el código completo para que lo puedan revisar por favor y no @Minerillo no estoy usando bootstrap.

Comment: Es muy raro lo que comentas. ¿Usas algún reset css como normalize? Si no, intenta y coméntanos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

logre solucionarlo haciendo lo siguiente:

```
/*-Mobile-*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

    --Elementos--

}

/*-Desktop-*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {

    --Elementos--

}
```

Como pueden ver definí dos espacios uno para móviles y otro para escritorio, al parecer el código CSS esta correcto aunque no entiendo porque solo me funciono así. Si alguien pudiera complementar la respuesta se los agradecería.

Comment: Esto se debe a que el código CSS no se adapta por si solo a las diferentes pantallas por lo que tienes que hacer uso de las media-queries para adaptar tu código según sea el tamaño de la pantalla.